# Highstock tooltip Formatter not able to display extra data

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

We started to develop in HighCharts but realised we needed to move to HighStock for the Zoom/slider functionality.

We had a graph working perfectly with the tooltip to display exactly the data we required as shown below from Highcharts.

[image]

To achieve this within in HighStock we just had the following code to format the ToolTip.

```
tooltip: {
    headerFormat: "",
    useHTML: true,
    formatter: function () {
        return '<span style="font-size: 10px">' + Highcharts.dateFormat('%I:%M:%S %P - %a, %e %b, %y', new Date(this.x)) + '</span><br/><span style="color:' + this.color + '">\u25CF</span> <b>' + this.point.name + '</b><br/>';
    }
},
```

We have attempted on the switch to HighStock to implement the same formatting, but all we receive through to the tooltip where it say's 'REASON_TIMED' is undefined as below.

[image]

our data object myData is created as follows :-

```
myData .push([Date.parse(obj.FixTimeLocal), obj.State, obj.Flags]);
```

This object worked correctly with the Fixtime being the X, state being the y and flags being a text description which would be populated in the ToolTip. We used keys to name the data x,y,name so we could access this.point.name. to add extra text to tooltip. Where are we going wrong ? we have tried for a couple of days now and can not get the data through.

```
Highcharts.stockChart('container', {
    //new chart style
    rangeSelector: {
       selected: 1
    },

    title: {
        text: 'Test Graph'
    },

    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime'
    },

    yAxis: {
        categories: ['Unknown', 'State 1', 'Disarmed', 'Armed', 'Service Timed', 'Unauthorised', 'Alert', 'Watch', 'Alarm'],
        title: {
            useHTML: true,
            text: 'Alert Type'
        }
    },

    tooltip: {
        headerFormat: "",
        useHTML: true,
        formatter: function () {
            var s = '<span style="font-size: 10px">' + Highcharts.dateFormat('%I:%M:%S %P - %a, %e %b, %y', new Date(this.x)) + '</span>';

            $.each(this.points, function () {
                s += '<br/><span style="color:' + this.color + '">\u25CF</span><b>' + this.point.name + '</b><br/>'; // Code falls over here this.point.name is not recognised.
            });

            return s;
        }
    },

    series: [{
        type: 'areaspline',
        keys: ['x', 'y', 'name'],
        data: myData,
        marker: {
            enabled: true,
            radius: 1.5
        },
        threshold: null,

        fillColor: {
            linearGradient: {
                x1: 0,
                y1: 0,
                x2: 0,
                y2: 1
            },
            stops: [
                [0, Highcharts.Color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[3]).setOpacity(0.5).get('rgba')],
                [1, Highcharts.Color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[3]).setOpacity(0).get('rgba')]
            ]
        },

color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[3],
lineWidth: 0.5,
threshold: null,
    }]
});
```

Comment: Can please you create a jsFiddle of your problem? It help there to debug the problem.

Comment: @ali Struggling to create the data object for the JS Fiddle. Just created the Fiddle but without data it was pointless (ignore the pun).

Comment: Whats the value of "myData" in series

Comment: @JalayOza A typical value would be, x : 2017/05/01, y : 5, name : "A string here up to 50 characters but in this test max is 10", the data structure is working perfectly in highcharts. I have a feeling the Keys are not working as I can not target this.point.name like I did in Highcharts

Comment: I have tried to replicate your issue with values you have. It looks that your chart is working ok on my side: http://jsfiddle.net/1sw02pm2/1/ However, I think that you issue may be related to dataGrouping in Highstock. You can try disabling it http://api.highcharts.com/highstock/plotOptions.series.dataGrouping.enabled

Comment: @GrzegorzBlachliński Thank you very much, my apologies I tried to create a fiddle, I could make one with it working just not with my data as you displayed so thought showing it would confuse the situation. Your disabling dataGrouping has fixed the issue !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to – Grzegorz Blachliński for identifying the issue.

Within my series I had to set the following. Which is now working with my data and I can target the point.name to get it to display in the Tooltip.

```
 dataGrouping: {
                enabled: false
            },
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this

see your html would be

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="height: 300px"></div>
```

And code might like this

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
        rangeSelector: {
       selected: 1
    },

    title: {
        text: 'Test Graph'
    },

        // Its your X data
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['2017/05/01', '2017/05/02', '2017/05/03', '2017/05/04', '2017/05/05', '2017/05/06','2017/05/07', '2017/05/08', '2017/05/09', '2017/05/10']
    },

    yAxis: {
        //categories: ['Unknown', 'State 1', 'Disarmed', 'Armed', 'Service Timed', 'Unauthorised', 'Alert', 'Watch', 'Alarm'],
        title: {
            useHTML: true,
            text: 'Alert Type'
        }
    },

tooltip: {
        headerFormat: "",
        useHTML: true,
        formatter: function () {
            var s = '<span style="font-size: 10px; width:100%;">' + Highcharts.dateFormat('%I:%M:%S %P - %a, %e %b, %y', new Date(this.x)) + '</span>';

            $.each(this.points, function () {
                s += '<br/><span style="color:' + this.color + '">\u25CF</span><b>' + this.point.name + '</b><br/>'; // Code falls over here this.point.name is not recognised.
            });

            return s;
        },
    },



series: [{
                type: 'areaspline',
        // its your yAxis category
        name: "Unknown",
        // Its your Y Data
        data: [5,10,56,22,54,35,32,26,36],
    },{
                type: 'areaspline',
        name: "State 1",
        // Its your Y Data value
        data: [10,30,59,22,24,55,52,66,46],
    }]

});
```

Here is live : https://jsfiddle.net/jalayoza/eaue85rb/6/

Hope this help

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to reply, unfortunately your solution will not work for my requirement's.